# Slope of p-orbitals at the nucleus

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, orbitals

Is there any analytic expression describing the slope of the p-orbital at the nucleus, for example for hydrogen.

Comment: Although I do not understand, what you mean with slope, there certainly is (for hydrogen), as the hydrogen eigenfunctions are analytically known.

Comment: The usual imagery for orbitals that you see in older chemistry textbooks are complete fiction. Orbitals do not "look" like that, and even if they did, there are no physically relevant features in "slopes", no matter how you define them. The only relevant quantities that one needs to be concerned about are quantum mechanical expectation values. Maybe you should reformulate the question by asking directly what it is that you are really trying to do. This question sounds like you have made yourself a misleading mental model, already, and you are trying to work with it.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @CuriousOne unless you are asking for $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} \iint \mathrm{d}\theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi \sin\theta \,\psi^*\psi$ which is the only quantity I could think imagine for which the question might be meaningful. But then I couldn't think of a use for the thing I wrote down.